# How to use "for loop" to get couples of indexes every time in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Let's assume I have this vector `v`:

```
v = seq(1,30,1)
```

I write this simple loop:

```
for(i in v) {
  print(i)
}
```

However, I would like to write a loop that gives me, in time, 1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, etc. I would then get:

```
[1] 1,2
[1] 3,4
[1] 5,6
[1] 7,8
...
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can generate `v` with step of 2.

```
v = seq(1,30,2)
for(i in v) {
  cat(paste(i, i + 1, sep = ','), '\n')
}

#1,2 
#3,4 
#5,6 
#7,8 
#9,10 
#11,12 
#13,14 
#...
```

Comment: thanks mate! Just one tweak, the result is a character and I am finding hard to turn it into numeric format, any idea?

Comment: print/paste0/cat would always turn the result into character but if you check `i` in the loop it is of type numeric so you can use it for other purposes like subsetting or any other mathematical operations as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your approach, try this:

```r
for(i in v[-length(v)]) {
  print(c(i, i+1))
}

[1] 1 2
[1] 2 3
[1] 3 4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the print command and use the method range

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

```
for i in range(0,len(v)-1,2):
    print(str(v[i])+","+str(v[i+1]))
```

In this way you should get

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `i` to a subset.

```
for(i in v) {
  print(v[0:1 + i])
}
# [1] 1 2
# [1] 2 3
# [1] 3 4
# [1] ...
```

Alternatively you could also consider this:

```
cbind(v[-length(v)], v[-1])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    3    4
# [4,]    4    5
# [5,]    5    6
# [6,]    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> for(i in v) if (i%%2) print(c(i,i+1))
[1] 1 2
[1] 3 4
[1] 5 6
[1] 7 8
[1]  9 10
[1] 11 12
[1] 13 14
[1] 15 16
[1] 17 18
[1] 19 20
[1] 21 22
[1] 23 24
[1] 25 26
[1] 27 28
[1] 29 30
```